# Rails - how to get response properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

```
uri = URI(some_url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```

Try to on browser, it returns result like this.

```
[
  {
    "id": 663,
    "name": "string1"
  },
  {
    "id": 644,
    "name": "string2"
  },
  {
    "id": 685,
    "name": "string3"
  },
]
```

But I am getting this error with my code.

```
Error: Net::HTTPBadResponse:wrong status line: "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"
```

Comment: can you share the value of some_url?

Comment: Try `request.use_ssl = true if uri.scheme == 'https'` before doing the request.

Comment: You're sending http request, but server accepts only https (this odd looking response is from SSL)

Comment: Does the URL start with `https`?